# Disable Shift-Option-Y for Á character for Bitwarden Firefox extension

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, firefox

I use the Bitwarden Firefox extension, and the keyboard shortcut to open it in the sidebar is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. This works some of the time. But when I'm focused on a form input, it just outputs the character <kbd>Á</kbd>.

Is there any place I can disable that special character? I'm using the GB keyboard. I've tried setting the shortcut in my keyboard settings like this, but it doesn't change anything.

[image: Screenshot of the Keyboard Preferences pane showing the App Shortcut section]

Comment: Mac's use option and shift option by default for special characters.  Can you set the Bitwarded shortcut to something using Command or Control instead?

Comment: OMG, you can! I got the procedure from here: https://community.bitwarden.com/t/ability-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts-in-firefox-60/42/8?u=myrtle. Go to about:addons, click the settings cog, and select “Manage Extension Shortcuts” from the dropdown menu. Thanks @tom-gewecke, do you want to post that as an answer?